# Form2 is unknown for Form1 in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I have created a new form by add new item in solution explorer and it's name is"Form2" but when I'm using below code in a button I see this error:

"namespace name Form2 could not be found"

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}
```

Why Form1 don't know class of Form2?

Comment: Error message already tells you: Something wrong with your namespaces. Check them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to your namespaces. Your form1 and form2 might not be in the same namespaces.
[image]